# L298N Motor Driver not working

Tags: power, motor, nodemcu

I am using a L298N motor driver to connect a motor with NodeMCU. But i did a few tests since a few tests while learning how to control it now when i connect it the motor doesn't even work. Then i removed the nodemcu and just used the motor driver to control the motor, then also it did not work. I don't know why.
I am new to controlling motors and this is my first time.

Also I am using 9v battery to power the motor driver.

l298n- https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B08SK2ZPYD/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

nodemcu - https://www.amazon.in/Lolin-NodeMCU-ESP8266-CP2102-Wireless/dp/B010O1G1ES/ref=sr_1_2?dchild=1&keywords=nodemcu&qid=1617973657&s=industrial&sr=1-2

Comment: Please post the schematic of your wiring.

Comment: Add links to each hardware item.  9V batteries are very poor choice for motors.

Comment: @gil so which battery do you suggest. I also suspected that it was not getting enough power.

Comment: I do not know your skills, and resources so I decline to make a recommendation. I use LAB power supplies and size batteries when the project if finished.